# Error: Cannot find module 'yallist'

Tags: angular, npm

Presento este error al momento de ejecutar  `ng serve` o  `npm` para ejecutar Angular , probe desisntalando node js , limpiando, etc ... y volviendo a instalar node pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error que se muestra en la imagen, que puedo hacer? he intentado buscar en foros pero no encuentro nada parecido a el error que tengo y no puedo ejecutar nada en Angular

```
PS C:\Users\jusei> npm --v
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module 'yallist'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\jusei\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\lru-cache\index.js
- C:\Users\jusei\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\classes\range.js
- C:\Users\jusei\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\classes\comparator.js
- C:\Users\jusei\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\index.js
- C:\Users\jusei\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\unsupported.js
- C:\Users\jusei\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\jusei\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jusei\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\node_modules\←[4mlru-cache←[24m\index.js:4:17)
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\jusei\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\lru-cache\\index.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\jusei\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\semver\\classes\\range.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\jusei\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\semver\\classes\\comparator.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\jusei\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\semver\\index.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\jusei\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\unsupported.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\jusei\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\jusei\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'←[39m
  ]
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo no usar imágenes para mostrar errores o código, por favor lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para entender cómo esperamos que se planteen las preguntas

Comment: Por otro lado, intenta reinstalar node/npm, es posible que algún fichero no se copiara bien durante la instalación o que el comando no tenga los permisos de lectura necesarios

Comment: ya lo intente por eso mismo pregunto que puedo hacer para solucionar ese error de ejecucion

Comment: pudiste resolverlo? me sale el mismo error y no logro dar con la solucion. si poder compartirla te lo agradezco!